# Export data.table and print cells content in new lines

Tags: r, dataframe, character, officer

Let's have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c('Warsaw; Nairobi'),c('Mogadishu; Ottawa'),c('Berlin; Paris'))
colnames(df)<-c('a','b','c')
```

Now it is time to export data to table .docx

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
my_doc <- read_docx()
export <- my_doc%>%body_add_table(df)
print(export, target = "my_path/table.docx")
```

I want to exchange semicolons to sign that will force the MS Word to print the capital cities in new lines within the same cell.

Like column on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `;` with `\n`:

```
df$a <- gsub("; ", "\\\n", df$a)
df$b <- gsub("; ", "\\\n", df$b)
df$c <- gsub("; ", "\\\n", df$c)

flextable(df)
```

[image]